# Restriction of sheaf of modules

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $\mathcal{F}$ be an $\mathcal{O}_x$-module. Let $V \subset U$ open subsets of the scheme $X$. Then the restriction map $\mathcal{F}(U) \to \mathcal{F}(V)$ is compatible with the restriction map $\mathcal{O}_X(U) \to \mathcal{O}_X(V)$.

I want to draw this as the commutative diagram with $\mathcal{O}_X(U) \to \mathcal{O}_X(V)$ in the top horizontal row and $\mathcal{F}(U) \to \mathcal{F}(V)$. I think this is what is meant by compatible.

What is the morphism between $\mathcal{O}_X(U) \to \mathcal{F}(U)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $\mathrm{res}^U_V: \mathscr{O}(U)\to \mathscr{O}(V)$ is the restriction map on the structure sheaf and $\rho^U_V: \mathscr{F}(U)\to \mathscr{F}(V)$ the restriction map on $\mathscr{F}$ as a *sheaf of abelian groups*. If $\mathscr{F}(U)$ is an $\mathscr{O}(U)$ module it means that there is a collection of maps $\alpha(U): \mathscr{O}(U)\times \mathscr{F}(U)\to \mathscr{F}(U)$ representing the action of $\mathscr{O}(U)$ on $\mathscr{F}(U)$. Then the compatibility is the commutativity of the following diagram:

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Another question: Using the fact that $\mathcal{O}(U) \times \mathcal{F}(U) \to \mathcal{F}(U)$ is equivalent to $\mathcal{O}(U) \to Hom(\mathcal{F}(U), \mathcal{F}(U)$, and similarly for the right hand side of the diagram. How do you rewrite this diagram to represent this relationship?

Comment: Do you know what sheaf hom is? Look here http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01CM in this new terminology basically you need to draw that $\mathscr{O}\to \mathrm{Hom}_{\mathscr{O}}(\mathscr{F}, \mathscr{F})$ is a morphism of $\mathscr{O}$-modules. Hence its diagram is like any other morphism of sheaves.

Comment: In general I would recommend reading Ravi Vakil's notes, Chapter two. He explains all of this stuff with patience (not too many people do unfortunately). You'll get a good grip on what's what once you're done with that chapter.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation. I see this exact diagram in Vakil but it was unclear from Hartshorne writing the word "compatible".